# PHP function not returning a value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array, return-value, undefined-variable

I have been working on a color palette system where a multidimensional array holds different color palettes. EX:

```
$palette['1']['borderColor'] = "black";
$palette['2']['borderColor'] = "white";
```

I have a function that should return a color palette item when called but for some reason it's not returning anything. Instead it says "Undefined variable:  palette"EX:

```
$palette['1'] = array(
    "borderColor"=> "#222222",
    "divColor1"=> "#00f2ff",
    "divColor2"=> "#222222",
    "headerColor"=> "rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.5)",
    "color1"=> "#00f2ff",
    "color2"=> "#e9ffdd"
  );

function getItem($number, $item) {
  return $palette[$number][$item];
}

$borderColor = getItem('1', 'borderColor');
echo "borderColor is> " . $borderColor . " <.";

//returns "borderColor is>  <."
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add `global $palette;` to your function in order to have access to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scope of PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452989/scope-of-php-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you wrote does not have the actual palette value.. Just pass the palette you want into the function.

```
$palette['1'] = array(
    "borderColor"=> "#222222",
    "divColor1"=> "#00f2ff",
    "divColor2"=> "#222222",
    "headerColor"=> "rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.5)",
    "color1"=> "#00f2ff",
    "color2"=> "#e9ffdd"
  );

function getItem($palette, $number, $item) {
  return $palette[$number][$item];
}

$borderColor = getItem($palette,'1', 'borderColor');
echo "borderColor is> " . $borderColor . " <.";
```

Another way to do this would be to make a simple class in which you could call your palettes.

```
class Palette {

  public function __construct($palette){

  $this->borderColor  = $palette['borderColor'];
  $this->divColor1    = $palette['divColor1'];
  $this->divColor2    = $palette['divColor2'];
  $this->headerColor  = $palette['headerColor'];
  $this->color1       = $palette['color1'];
  $this->color2       = $palette['color2'];

  }


}

$palette['1'] = array(
    "borderColor"=> "#222222",
    "divColor1"=> "#00f2ff",
    "divColor2"=> "#222222",
    "headerColor"=> "rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.5)",
    "color1"=> "#00f2ff",
    "color2"=> "#e9ffdd"
  );

$black = new Palette($palette['1']);
$white = new Palette($palette['2']);

echo $black->borderColor;
echo $white->borderColor;
```

Comment: I get it!. Thank you. I was not familiar with the $global keyword. I implemented the fix and it works perfectly! I will also try out the class idea, I could see that helping in other areas of my program.

Comment: Cool glad you got it work..  Classes are very powerful tools.  Once you get how they work, you will like them alot.

Answer (score 2):

Actually inside your getItem function the variable *$palette* is not available so either you've to pass it on your **getItem** function or just add **global** keyword  on your function's **$palette** variable.

**Way 1:**

```
function getItem($palette, $number, $item) {
  return $palette[$number][$item];
}

$borderColor = getItem($palette,'1', 'borderColor');
```

**Way 2:**

```
function getItem($number, $item) {
  global $palette; // it will be available here
  return $palette[$number][$item];
}

$borderColor = getItem('1', 'borderColor');
```

**DEMO** https://eval.in/988491